# OpenWrap: test-wrap, how does it work?

Tags: openwrap

I am using the beta of OpenWrap 2.0. OpenWrap contains support to run unit-tests, my question is how exactly does this work?

Should I see it as a test-runner that takes a built wrap, searches for the tests included in the wrap, and tries to run them? Is it required to include the tests inside the wrap?

How does the dependency resolving work in the context of tests? I can specify a tests-scope which adds extra dependencies required for the tests. When are those dependencies used? I assume it is used to build the test-projects, and to run the tests with test-wrap? However, when I do include the tests in the wrap, shouldn't those test-scoped dependencies also be considered dependencies for the wrap, or are they only used as dependencies when I try to execute "test-wrap"?

Another thing I was wondering about in the context of the tests, is the difference between compile-time and run-time dependencies.

As an example, I have a project API that specifies an API. Next to that project, I have 2 other projects Impl1 and Impl2 that each specify a different implementation of that API. And next to that I have a test project API.Tests that contains tests against the API. The tests use dependency injection to inject either Impl1 or Impl2 to run the tests.
In this case, the API.Tests project only has a compile time dependency on the API (and should only have that available as a compile time dependency). When running the tests however, the project has a run-time dependency on Impl1 or Impl2. Any suggestions on how to package this?

Answer (score 0):

test-wrap will be able to run a test-runner for tests that are shipping as part of a pacakge (in /tests).

The implementation right now is not up-to-date anymore, mostly because packages do not include the testdriven.net test runner, which makes running those tests rather complicated. I've not re-evaluated our plans for this yet because of this reason.

OpenWrap 2 uses scopes to define dependencies that only apply to a certain subset of your code. In the case of tests, provided you have the correct dicrectory-structure instruction in the descriptor, your project will pull in those dependencies in the correct scope.

That said we don't preserve that information in the assembly, so when you run those tests we don't load up the dependencies for the test scope, which we should probably do (at least for tests). All assemblies in your package are however injected in the current appdomain, so for your scenario, provided you have your tests in /tests, you just need to package all those assemblies in the same package and it should just work.

The same mechanism will

Comment: You mean a /tests folder in the resulting wrap that includes all required dlls?

Comment: The test assemblies. The assemblies in /bin- are already loaded.